# Vega compute relative change based on another column value

Tags: json, visualization, vega

Suppose I have the following vega data table:

```
c x y
a 5 10
a 6 12
a 7 14
a 8 16
b 5 20
b 6 22
b 7 24
b 8 26
```

I want to compute the relative change in y when `x = 6` for both a and b. First, I need to find y value for `x = 6`, `{c: a, y: 12}` and `{c: b, y: 22}`. Now apply `datum.y - 12` for a and `datum.y - 22` for b. How to apply the appropriate transformation to get the relative y?

The final output would look like:

```
c x y  newY
a 5 10 -2
a 6 12 0
a 7 14 2
a 8 16 4
b 5 20 -2
b 6 22 0
b 7 24 2
b 8 26 4
```

For more clarification:

1. find the y for x = 6 => for a, y = 12 and for b, y=22
2. COmpute newY as y-12 for a and y - 22 for b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want or how you want to plot but the following seems to meet you requirements.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"c": "a", "x": 5, "y": 10},
        {"c": "a", "x": 6, "y": 12},
        {"c": "a", "x": 7, "y": 14},
        {"c": "a", "x": 8, "y": 16},
        {"c": "b", "x": 5, "y": 20},
        {"c": "b", "x": 6, "y": 22},
        {"c": "b", "x": 7, "y": 24},
        {"c": "b", "x": 8, "y": 26}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "as": "aKey", "expr": "datum.c+datum.x"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "table2",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "bKey",
          "expr": "datum.c=='a'?'b'+datum.x:'a'+datum.x"
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "table",
          "key": "aKey",
          "fields": ["bKey"],
          "values": ["y"],
          "as": ["newY"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "relativeChange",
          "expr": "datum.newY-datum.y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": []
}
```

**OR**

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"c": "a", "x": 5, "y": 10},
        {"c": "a", "x": 6, "y": 12},
        {"c": "a", "x": 7, "y": 14},
        {"c": "a", "x": 8, "y": 16},
        {"c": "b", "x": 5, "y": 20},
        {"c": "b", "x": 6, "y": 22},
        {"c": "b", "x": 7, "y": 24},
        {"c": "b", "x": 8, "y": 26}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "window",
          "groupby":["x"],
          "sort": {"field": "key", "order": "ascending"},
          "ops": ["lead"],
          "fields": ["y"],
          "as": ["newY"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "relativeChange",
          "expr": "datum.newY-datum.y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": []
}
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"c": "a", "x": 5, "y": 10},
        {"c": "a", "x": 6, "y": 12},
        {"c": "a", "x": 7, "y": 14},
        {"c": "a", "x": 8, "y": 16},
        {"c": "b", "x": 5, "y": 20},
        {"c": "b", "x": 6, "y": 22},
        {"c": "b", "x": 7, "y": 24},
        {"c": "b", "x": 8, "y": 26}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "as": "i", "expr": "datum.x==6?datum.y:null"},
        {
          "type": "window",
          "sort": {
            "field": ["i"],
            "order": [ "ascending"]
          },
          "ops": ["next_value"],
          "fields": ["i"],
          "as": ["j"], "groupby":["c"]
        },
        {"type": "formula", "as": "newY", "expr": "datum.y-datum.j"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": []
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added some more clarification in the question. I don't want to get the relative change for the same y between a and b. It's within group a, find the y corresponding to x = 6 and then subtract that value for all the other y for group a.

Comment: How do you get newY of -4,0,3 and 5 for b?

Comment: To avoid confusion, I changed the original data and newY and forgot to update it in the 2nd table, causing more confusion. Sorry! I roll backed the changes.

Comment: I've provided an update at the end for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using Vega *lookup* transform similar to David's first answer but producing correct results that you expect.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGh0s.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  
  "signals":[
    {
      "name": "signal_target_x",
      "update": "6"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table_input",
      "values": [
        {"c": "a", "x": 5, "y": 10},
        {"c": "a", "x": 6, "y": 12},
        {"c": "a", "x": 7, "y": 14},
        {"c": "a", "x": 8, "y": 16},
        {"c": "b", "x": 5, "y": 20},
        {"c": "b", "x": 6, "y": 22},
        {"c": "b", "x": 7, "y": 24},
        {"c": "b", "x": 8, "y": 26}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "inputKey",
          "expr": "datum['c'] + datum['x']"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "table_analysis",
      "source": "table_input",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "targetKey",
          "expr": "datum['c'] + signal_target_x"
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "table_input",
          "key": "inputKey",
          "fields": ["targetKey"],
          "values": ["y"],
          "as": ["targetY"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "newY",
          "expr": "datum['y'] - datum['targetY']"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nice solution Roy.